# How to find Confluence Attachments on the disk

Tags: confluence

Confluence stores attachments in a wacky way and its nearly impossible to follow their own instructions on how to find where attachments are stored. Here is their documentation: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/hierarchical-file-system-attachment-storage-704578486.html.

I'm using CentOS and Mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian support gave me the following and I wanted to share with the community because it really shouldn't be that complicated to find where files are stored on your machine. Here's the Mysql query:

```
select concat('<confluence_home>/attachments/ver003/', spaceid % 250, '/', spaceid / 1000 % 250, '/', spaceid, '/', pageid % 250, '/', pageid / 1000 % 250, '/', pageid, '/', en prevver is null then contentid else prevver end, '/', version ) as DiskLoc, spaceid, pageid, contentid, version from CONTENT where title like '%NAME OF FILE%' and contenttype
= 'ATTACHMENT' and pageid in ( select c.contentid FROM CONTENT c JOIN SPACES s ON s.spaceid = c.spaceid where c.contenttype = 'PAGE' and s.spaceid is not null AND c.prevver IS NULL);
```

Just replace NAME OF FILE with the name of your file

Comment: There's a typo in the case expression in the middle. Also, this query would look a lot better if you'd put some line breaks and indentation into it.